# Fatal error throwing after adding jetty server and build it

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I included jetty maven plugin to run the application but while building I am getting below error. Log dependency and plugin mentioned below to check.

My pom.xml contains

**Dependency Details**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
 </dependency>
```

**Plugin Details**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>app.log.root</name>
                <value>${project.basedir}/target/logs</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <war>${project.basedir}/target/Application.war</war>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>7777</port>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <!-- stop any previous instance to free up the port -->
                <goal>stop</goal>
                <goal>run-war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please find the error details

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:435)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.<clinit>(AbstractLifeCycle.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.AbstractConfigurationConverter.instantiateObject(AbstractConfigurationConverter.java:111)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.fromConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:88)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:135)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:207)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1357)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:724)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 40 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.fromConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:90)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:135)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:207)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:137)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultPluginManager.java:1357)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:724)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Comment: You're missing the actual SLF4J library.

Comment: Please let me know which SLF4J library need to use

Comment: The main one, `slf4j-api`.

Comment: Added but still facing the same issue . Could you please guide me on this also let me know if anything missing

Comment: The interface `org.slf4j.Logger` is in `slf4j-api`. SLF4J has good documentation.